# Cross validation for classifiers

Tags: classification, cross-validation

Cross-validation is used for estimation of model.

I misunderstand the concept. If different part of corpus is used for training per each iteration, then each iteration generates the different model. So, what's validated? Only selected features?

Comment: This question would be better asked on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The performance of model on different parts of same data! Because ultimately you would train the model on whole data.

Comment: @VivekKumar - that's exactly what I misunderstand. Supposedly, you train Neural on some set. Given the same features you get different weights on each subset of set. Weight vector is main part of model. That means each iteration you get different model.

Comment: @G5W - 10x. Just asked.